# add background image on Static Cell UITableView

Tags: uitableview, swift3, xcode8

anyone know how to put a background image on Static UITableView? I have a dynamic prototypes UITableView and a Static UITableView.(Both tableView show many rows) And I want to use the same background image on both tableview. But I not sure how to add a background image on Static Cells UITableView. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps.

You can add this code to viewdidload

```
   let TempImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "your_image"))
   TempImageView.frame = self.TableView.frame
   self.TableView.backgroundView = TempImageView
```

You will need to create tableview class and you will have to add the methods as below -

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return super.tableView .numberOfRows(inSection: section)
    }
```

Also make sure cell background is set to clear color

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: No, you have to write this code in viewcontroller where you are using the tableview.

Comment: Do I need to create a new cocoa touch class UItableView controller file? But when I created, it automatic generated some codes. I already I have number of cells and sections in my Static UITableView on storyboard.

Comment: you don't need to create a new  UItableView controller.

Comment: I tried to write those code on viewcontroller.swift. but I got this "static table view are only valid when embedded in UITableview controller instances"

Comment: Is your static table view a part of your view controller? Then you need to write the code in view controller . If your static table view in part of UItableView controller then you need to create the new class for it. And create the outlet of the tableview and use this code. You won't be able to set the bg image for your tableview on storyboard directly. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi CST, I am still a little confused. So I have a tab bar controller, and when I tab one of the tab bar icon on the bottom, it pop up my static Static UITableView. I do need to create a new class for this Static UITableView to add back ground image?

Comment: hey, do you want to add background image to the cell or to the tableview?

Comment: you will have to create a tableview class to add the bg image to your static table.

Comment: I want to add a background image to the static tableview. (not in the cell)

Comment: I just don't know where should I put those code that you provide above. If I create a UItableview class, it automatic generated some codes that I don't need. (the number of rows.) I already have rows on my static tableview.

Comment: hey, i have edited the answer. Check if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that!